# Offset error when rotating an image with AffineTransform Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to rotate an image using the `AffineTransform` class. However, when rotating for example 90 degrees the image changes its width and height values causing offsets that I would like to remove.

This is what I have tried

OpRotate.java

```
    public BufferedImage filter(BufferedImage src, BufferedImage dest) {

        // Parameter auswerten
        float rotationAngle = ((float) attributes.getAttributeByName("Desired rotation angle").getValue());

        AffineTransform rotationTransformation = new AffineTransform();
        double middlePointX = src.getHeight() / 2;
        double middlePointY = src.getWidth() / 2;


        rotationTransformation.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle), middlePointX, middlePointY);

        operation = new AffineTransformOp(rotationTransformation, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

        return operation.filter(src, dest);

    }
```

After rotating the image 90 degrees to the right, the result looks like the following:

[image: result]

Comment: check the AffineTransformOp page - it says there on filter about offsets and such - you want to draw the center of the image to see what happens and where it happens

Comment: Are you always rotating 90 degrees (or multiples of 90 degrees)? Or do you allow arbitrary angles?

Answer (score 0):

Rotating an image using `AffineTransformOp` is (in my mind) a little counter-intuitive... Rotation itself is easy, but as you have probably already found out, the hard part is translating correctly, so that the upper-left part of the image (or it's bounding box, in case of a non-quadrant rotation) *after rotation* hits perfectly at the origin.

If you need to rotate an arbitrary angle, you can use the following, quite general code:

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage src, double degrees) {
    double angle = toRadians(degrees); // Allows any angle

    double sin = abs(sin(angle));
    double cos = abs(cos(angle));

    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    // Compute new width and height
    double newWidth = width * cos + height * sin;
    double newHeight = height * cos + width * sin;

    // Build transform
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.translate(newWidth / 2.0, newHeight / 2.0);
    transform.rotate(angle);
    transform.translate(-width / 2.0, -height / 2.0);

    BufferedImageOp operation = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    return operation.filter(src, null);
}
```

However, if you only want to rotate multiples of 90 degrees, you can use this slightly faster variant:

```
public static BufferedImage rotate90(BufferedImage src, int quadrants) {
    // Allows any multiple of 90 degree rotations (1, 2, 3)

    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    // Compute new width and height
    boolean swapXY = quadrants % 2 != 0;
    int newWidth = swapXY ? height : width;
    int newHeight = swapXY ? width : height;

    // Build transform
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.translate(newWidth / 2.0, newHeight / 2.0);
    transform.quadrantRotate(quadrants);
    transform.translate(-width / 2.0, -height / 2.0);

    BufferedImageOp operation = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR); // 1:1 mapping

    return operation.filter(src, null);
}
```